# Prove that certain logarithm function is Completely Monotone function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A function is said to be completely monotone function if $n$-th derivative of the function exists and

$$
(-1)^n f^{n}(x) \geq 0
$$

where, $f^{n}(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of the function. [Note that $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$].

Prove that

$$
f(x)=ln(a+\frac{b}{x})
$$

is a completely monotone function with $a\geq 1$ and $b>0$.

Sol:
$$
e^{f(x)}=a+\frac{b}{x} \\
f^{(1)}(x)=f'(x)=-\frac{b}{x^2}e^{-f(x)} \\
f^{(2)}(x)=f''(x)=-f^{(1)}(x) \left\{ f^{(1)}(x)+\frac{2}{x} \right\}
$$

I don't seem to find any pattern in such differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot prove this: $$(-1)^n f^{n}(x) \geq 0$$
But for the generalization, consider
$$f(x) = ln(\frac{ax+b}{x})$$
$$f(x) = ln(ax+b) - lnx$$
$$f^{(1)}(x) = a(ax+b)^{-1} - \frac{1}{x}$$
$$f^{(2)}(x) = -a^2(ax+b)^{-2} + \frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$f^{(3)}(x) = 2a^3(ax+b)^{-3} - \frac{2}{x^3}$$
$$f^{(4)}(x) = -6a^4(ax+b)^{-4} + \frac{2 \cdot 3}{x^4}$$
Hence,
$$f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!a^n(ax+b)^{-n} + (-1)^n \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}a^n(n-1)!}{(ax+b)^{n}} + (-1)^n \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}$$

Hope this helps

Comment: You made a little mistake for the differentiation of $1/x$ type-terms otherwise, it's good hint, something that I wanted, let me see if I can solve it with or not.

Comment: Yes I overlooked

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the calculations in Saransh's answer are not quite right. Correcting them,  we need to show that $$
\frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}\ge\frac{a^n(n-1)!}{(ax+b)^n}.$$ So it's enough to show that $$\frac1x\ge\frac{a}{ax+b},$$or $$ax+b\ge ax.$$

Comment: This, along with Saransh solution, completes the answers.

Answer (score 0):

From Saransh's post,
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}a^n(n-1)!}{(ax+b)^{n}} + (-1)^n \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}
$$
so,
$$
(-1)^n f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}a^n(n-1)!}{(ax+b)^{n}} + (-1)^{2n} \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n} \\
= \frac{-a^n(n-1)!}{(ax+b)^{n}} + \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n} 
$$
Now, to prove, that $(-1)^n f^{(n)}(x)\geq 0$, follow David'd post.